# Is there a way to partially fill text with different colours?

Tags: css, svg, canvas

Here is what I'm trying to achieve:
[image]

Is there a way to do this with a W3 web technology, e.g. SVG, Canvas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can, by using the `text-fill-color` and `background-clip` properties.

```css
html, body {
  background: #000;
}

p {
  margin: 0px;
}

#clip {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(127, 127, 127, 1) 23%, rgba(234, 85, 7, 1) 20%, rgba(234, 85, 7, 1) 57%, rgba(127, 127, 127, 1) 59%);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  font-size: 8vw;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<p id="clip">Lorem ipsum dolor sit </p>
```

**NOTE:** Visit [this link](https://css-tricks.com/how-to-do-knockout-text/) for more information.

Comment: Brilliant solution, thank you!